# Xamarin.Forms, picker, issue with displaying SelectedItem

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin.Forms application, have two pickers on page. Then I have view model for this page:

```
public class ExpenseEntriesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ExpenseEntriesViewModel()
    {
        // getting data from server here

        if (ExpenseEntriesDateRangeInfo.AvailableYears.Count > 0)
        {
            // AvailableYears is List<int>
            SelectedYear = ExpenseEntriesDateRangeInfo.AvailableYears.Max();
        }

        SelectedMonth =
            // AvailableMonths is List<MonthValue>
            ExpenseEntriesDateRangeInfo.AvailableMonths.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MonthNumber == DateTime.Today.Month);
    }

    public DateRangeInfo ExpenseEntriesDateRangeInfo { get; set; }

    private int _selectedYear;
    public int SelectedYear
    {
        get => _selectedYear;
        set
        {
            _selectedYear = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private MonthValue _selectedMonth;
    public MonthValue SelectedMonth
    {
        get => _selectedMonth;
        set
        {
            _selectedMonth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedMonth));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Here is the MonthValue model:

```
public class MonthValue
{
    public int MonthNumber { get; set; }
    public string MonthName { get; set; }
}
```

Models and data are correct, I went through code with debugger and checked.
XAML markup of pickers:

```
<Picker Title="Month"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ExpenseEntriesDateRangeInfo.AvailableMonths}"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding MonthName}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonth, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<Picker Title="Year"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ExpenseEntriesDateRangeInfo.AvailableYears}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedYear, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Year picker binds to list of int, works perfect. Month picker works with MonthValue array and do not displaying MonthName property as SelectedItem name, this is the issue.
Is there any solution or thoughts? Pretty simple case as for me.

UPDATE. Added project with issue demo [here](https://github.com/Dried09/xamarin-forms-issue-app)

It tested on real android device (Android 6.0, API 23)

Comment: Looks like you do not have `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding MonthName}"` on your second picker.

Comment: Disagree, ItemDisplayBinding is for proper displaying list of items to pick when user tap on picker, it works properly with, and wrong without (shows ToString() output MonthValue object)

Comment: `ExpenseEntriesDateRangeInfo` how is this *not* null; I am not seeing where this has been instantiated; is it static?

Comment: @Dried09 Got it. If `AvailableYears` is integers list then you should be able to bind `ItemDisplayBinding` to self.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I omitted ExpenseEntriesDateRangeInfo init for more clear code. I receiving it's data from server, it's checked and works properly.

Comment: @DenysDenysenko Year picker works properly, problem only with Month picker with complex object bound to it.
If you have primitive items for picker you don't have to point exact property because you have the only one

Comment: The range of `DateTime.Today.Month` is from 0 to 11 in Android ,While in iOS it's from 1 to 12 .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Good note, will keep in mind. However I think it's not a root of issue.

Comment: So can you share a sample (you can use static data) so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: It might be just Xamarin issue, are you able to override `ToString` for `MonthValue`?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Actually all of the code here. Will try.

Comment: @DenysDenysenko I tried this way. Same result, nothing.

Comment: Did it display nothing ?Or wrong value? I create a demo and it works fine .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT It display placeholder, it may mean two things: SelectedItem did not set correct or it can't properly get MonthName from item. If I select manually after app started - it sets correct. I think there is some problem with bind\set order, because in general it works but not able to get value that set in constructor of view model.

Comment: My project works fine ,so can you share your sample ? Your code seems has no issue.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I added sample project that demonstrates issue. See update above.

Comment: The issue maybe cause by your code , project configuration , sdk version and so on .So as I said it works fine on my side and If you can provide a full sample which contains the issue ,it will be helpful to solve it.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I provided part of my project that completely reproduce this issue as separate ready-to-launch project and put it to github, link available above. Did you check it out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200616/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-dried09).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding in Xamarin.Forms works not so obvious and require some boilerplate code.

I add AvailableMonths and AvailableYears properties directly to ExpenseEntriesViewModel and typed as ObservableCollection and ObservableCollection accordingly and it works now as expected.